# Esri maps coordinate convert

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis, esri, esri-maps

I'm trying to implement `Esri maps` into a WPF project and I can't get my head around the coordinates they use. The old system used `lat/long` so I need to get the same values from Esri.

When I get the MapPoint object for the current position of the map, its X value is `300464.16687909653` and its Y value is `524877.02696703083`. I need to take these values and convert them to lat and lon, then convert them the other way whenever necessary. I'm struggling finding anything that can help with this conversion, I presumed there would be some easy C# conversion methods lying around but I can't seem to find them.

Can anyone help?

(Just to be clear, I'm using the .NET sdk)

Comment: First you should get to know which coordinate-reference-system this coords are in. Might be Web-mercator, for example...

Comment: Do you have some more `real world`coordinates? May be the dot must be shifted four characters to the left? If so https://www.google.de/maps/@52.4877027,30.0464167,5z is anywhere in Belarus and X / Y changed it is Iran.

Comment: What's the origin of the Esri Maps?

Comment: if you look on the map at: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/16/ . You can see that -1.9995856060759, 53.701171875 is the centre of England in Lat/Lon. It also gives other coordinates (which are the same as what Esri/ArcGis provide) which are -222592.851466, 7079301.949831. I need to find a way to convert between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your last comment I got it and as @HimBromBeere mentioned - the coordinates are WGS84 (World Mercator) and WGS84 (GPS). It's EPSG:3395 and EPSG:4326.

[image]

You may try the [Online coordinate converter](http://tool-online.com/en/coordinate-converter.php#) by yourself.

Next to the coordinate reference system (CRS) dropdown box you can click and display the CRS's Parameters:

**EPSG:3395**

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / World Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3395"],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

**EPSG:4326**

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

Going deeper into this you may have a look at the following links. DotSpatial is a geographic information system library written for .NET 4. It allows developers to incorporate spatial data, analysis and mapping functionality into their applications or to contribute GIS extensions to the community (see second link).

1. [How to perform transformations using
   ProjNet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23425/how-to-perform-transformations-using-projnet)
2. [How to transform Lambert coordinates in
   C#?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27641/how-to-transform-lambert-coordinates-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

If you directly get a X,Y from ESRI Map then i would assume you haven't do any reprojection yet. So that the coordinates should still in EPSG:102100 which ESRI Web Mercator.

As your requirement is project the point to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) to get longitude and latitude, there are a lot of .Net libraries that you can use for this task such as proj4Net. Also there are multiple web APIs can do that too like ESRI Javascript API: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/util_project.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert from distances to coordinates.
You need a reference coordinate to do the conversion.

The X and Y your provided should be longitude and latitude distance in meters.

Here are the formulas you might need.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29157/how-do-i-convert-the-distance-between-two-lat-long-points-into-feet-meters

So you need to figure out what the X and Y are.
I suspect they are in WGS84 Antarctic Polar Stereographic (EPSG:3031), which is a system referring to -90°, 0°.

Update: According to the comments,please, it says clearly it's Mercator projection, and there is even a link on the page to the google result.

here is a C# solution:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator#C.23

Comment: "longitude distance in meters" What? That makes no sense to me. Depending on the actual reference-system the corrds are either angles as defined on an ellipsoid (e.g. WGS84) or rectangular units (e.g. meters as defined on a plain map). Moreover only x corresponds to  longitude, y corresponds to latitude.